# How to correctly pass more than one parameter

Tags: angular, sqlite, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm filtering products through a select in a modal. I was able to filter by regions: south, north, center and west. But I need to filter by region, filter by product category. So this is my query

```
getProdutosregiao(id, categoria_id) {             

return new Promise<Produto[]>((resolve, reject) => {
let sql = "SELECT TP.NOM_PATHIMAGEM, TP.NOM_PRODUTO, TS.NOM_SUBCATEGORIA, 
TP.DESC_PRODUTO, TP.VAL_PRODUTO, TP.CATEGORIA_ID " + 
        "FROM TB_PRODUTO TP " +
        "INNER JOIN TB_SUBCATEGORIA TS " +
        "ON TS.ID = TP.SUBCATEGORIA_ID " +
        "INNER JOIN TB_CATEGORIA TC " +
        "ON TC.ID = TP.CATEGORIA_ID " +
        "WHERE REGIAO_ID = " + id +
        " AND TC.ID = " + categoria_id ; 
     //       " AND SUBCATEGORIA_ID =  ";
  this.executeQuery(sql).then(data => {
  let regions = [];
  if (data!= undefined)
  data.forEach(function (row) {
  let region: Produto = { nom_pathimagem: row[0], nom_produto: row[1], 
  nom_subcategoria: row[2], desc_produto: row[3], val_produto: row[4], 
  desc_desconto: row[5], desc_experiencia: row[6], nom_endereco: row[7], 
  nom_complemento: row[8], nom_bairro: row[9], nom_cidade: row[10], cod_uf: 
  row[11], num_cep: row[12], desc_funcionamento: row[13], 
  nom_pathimagem_desc: row[14],  regiao_id: row[15], categoria_id: row[16] }
  regions.push(region);
});
resolve(regions);
}).catch(error => {
console.log(error);
});
});
```

Filtro-Modal.TS

```
 selecionaregiao(id, categoria_id) {
 this.db.getProdutosregiao(id, categoria_id)
 .then(data => this.produtos = data)
 .catch(error => console.log('Something want wrong!'));
 console.log('passou em tudo')
 }`enter code here`
```

Filtro-Modal-HTML

```
 <ion-select class="selectclass" (ionChange)="selecionaregiao($event)" 
 [(ngModel)]="regiao" >
 <ion-option *ngFor="let regiao of regioes" [value]="regiao.id" 
 class="optionclass">{{regiao.nom_regiao}}</ion-option>
 </ion-select>
```

But I get the error: "ERROR Error: no such column: undefined." And if I remove the parameter (cateogira_id), it works normally and filtering by region only. Am I passing the wrong parameter? Thanks for any help, Good morning!

Answer (score 0):

You are only passing $event to the method

```
(ionChange)="selecionaregiao($event)
```

If categoria_id is not part of the event, you will need to pass it as an argument to your method.

Comment: Thanks for answering.
Do you know how I pass by argument? I was wondering if it is possible to pass more than 1 parameter, I am using "WHERE / AND" but unsuccessfully using "AND"

Comment: what i am referring to is in your html.

Comment: sorry was trying to create a new line and it added the comment.

Try creating a console.log in Filtro-Modal.TS, something like this. console.log(id, categoria_id) I suspect categoria_id is null or undefined here.

if it is, then in your html you would need to do this (ionChange)="selecionaregiao($event, templateRf.value )

<ion-option #templateRef *ngFor="let regiao of regioes" [value]="regiao.id" 
 class="optionclass">{{regiao.nom_regiao}}</ion-option>
 </ion-select>